# Is there a way to add only a name to an r data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a way to add new columns to a data.frame and populate them with NAs (to be filled by a later function), where the titles of the new column come from a vector of characters (strings).

Example: 
What I'd like to do is add some new columns based on the subject column of this data.frame

```
exam_results <- data.frame(
  subject = c("maths", "economics", "chemistry"),
  final_score = c(70, 78, 61),
  midterm_score = c(53, 66,40)
)
```

i.e:

```
# new object for new df
exam_results_new_columns <- exam_results

# get the names of the different subjects
subjects <- unique(exam_results$subject)

column_names <- c()

for (i in 1:length(subjects)) {
  column_names[i] <- paste0("subject_", subjects[i])
  exam_results_new_columns$i <- NA
}
```

This will produce the following df:

| subject | final_score | midterm_score | i |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| maths | 70 | 53 | NA |
| economics | 78 | 66 | NA |
| chemistry | 61 | 40 | NA |

but what I would like is:

| subject | final_score | midterm_score | subject_economics | subject_chemistry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| maths | 70 | 53 | NA | NA |
| economics | 78 | 66 | NA | NA |
| chemistry | 61 | 40 | NA | NA |

is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Try with `exam_results_new_columns[[column_names[i]]] <- NA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *for* cycle, use square brackets `[]` instead of the dollar sign `$`

```
subjects <- unique(exam_results$subject)
column_names <- paste0("subject_", subjects)

for(i in column_names)
  exam_results_new_columns[,i] <- NA
```

Output

```
#     subject final_score midterm_score subject_maths subject_economics subject_chemistry
# 1     maths          70            53            NA                NA                NA
# 2 economics          78            66            NA                NA                NA
# 3 chemistry          61            40            NA                NA                NA
```